# UWP styles and themes in a nuget cannot find resource file

Tags: xaml, uwp, styles, resourcedictionary, class-library

I have a UWP project and a class library for theme dictionary and some control default styles all merged into 1 file called "Themes.xaml" and I reference to that project and simply import it in "app.xaml" like so :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GI.UI/Themes.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/_FontSizes.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and it works as expected but when I create a nuget with the same styles project and use that instead, then project throws an exception it is unable to locate Themes.xaml at this path.

### Update 1

I also tried adding an empty code behind file with "InitializeComponent()" for the ResourceDictionary "Themes.xaml" and it works perfectly when I import in the way showed below, but again it only works when I reference the project and doesn't work with nuget.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <theme:Themes />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/_FontSizes.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

(Themes.xaml.cs) Resource Dictionary code behind.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace GI.UI
{
    public sealed partial class Themes : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public Themes() => InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Themes.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
x:Class="GI.UI.Themes"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:BelowWindows10version1809="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractNotPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, 7)"
xmlns:Windows10version1809="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, 7)"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<!-- some styles and themes here -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

### Update 2

Noticed this warning of an exception by xaml compiler .

[image]

So Now I have the code of that nuget project along with almost empty sample app, feel free to reference from project and then try referencing from nuget package as well.

**project url** : https://github.com/touseefbsb/UWP_Styles_Nuget

**nuget package** : https://www.nuget.org/packages/GI.UI/0.0.16

I have also given the **nusepc** file in the project which I used to create the package.

**Note**

When I create the nuget file I get following warning

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean when you installed the nuget package which created by class library in the main project and tried to reference the Themes.xaml, it throwed can't locate the Themes.xaml? In addition, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: yes thats exactly what happened, Ill work on a sample and will provide one

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Please look at the Update 2 part of that question, I would really appreciate it, thanks

Comment: I notices that there is no file names `Theme.xaml`, in the package I see `Themes.xaml`

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy yes ill update my question with new file names, but file name isnt the issue, it wasnt working with theme.xaml and niether was it working with themes.xaml the reference name is correct that is why it works perfect when I reference the project itself.

Comment: actually I already updated the question there is no theme.xaml reference there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by following the folder structure as shown below :

[image]

and then editing nuspec file the following way :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///GI.Standards.Theme/Theme.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/_FontSizes.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Using the ms-appx to refer to a file that comes from your app's package.

```
Source="ms-appx:///LibraryName/Folder/File.xaml"
```

Comment: I did a litle testing using your nuget package. I couldnt get the Sample app running but i got some ideas. It appers that when you compile a class library containing a xaml file, it is converted into a xbf file and you need to include it manually. Here the reference: dschenkelman.github.io/2014/06/25/… 

You could also try removing the dot in GI.UI hope it helps

Comment: the link u provided seems incomplete, can u post it again ?

Comment: https://dschenkelman.github.io/2014/06/25/windows-phone-8-1-nuget-packages-with-xaml-components/ sorry

Comment: I could be wrong and a class works just as fine, but whenever I write ResourceDictionaries for UWP and WPF, they're only a XAML file (no code behind w/CTOR). I've only seen Xamarin.Forms require class approach